# Make a custom from calculator for payment

Tags: plugins, forms

I am stuck in making the payment form.

I want to make a custom form that has a formula for the total price, that price will redirect to a payment gateway that has a payment method like Google Pay and the user will able to make the payment. For this, I research and found some plugins like **cost calculator**, **contact form 7**, **bitform**, and more like this. But I could not do that thing and max all plugins asked for pro features to do so as I also want to make this as cheap as possible. Can I make this thing with some help ??